# How to set dynamic object values with Vue/Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm struggling to understand how to dynamically create & populate a key: value pairs in an object in my state using Vue/Vuex, here's an example:
`dataObject: {}` (in state), and a mutation that creates the new key:value pairs:

```
  setdataObjectProps: (state, payload) => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(
      state.dataObject
    )) {
      if (key == payload[0]) {
        dataObject.total_operation_time = payload[1];
        dataObject.machine_name = payload[2];
      }
    }
  },
```

This solution works, but the key:value pairs should already be existing in the object (i've set them to empty strings).
I tried using `Vue.set()` like this:

```
Vue.set(dataObject.total_operation_time,  payload[1]);
Vue.set(dataObject.machine_name,  payload[2]);
```

However, i'm struggling to understand how to make it work since it expects second parameter that's the index/name, if i understand correctly. Can someone explain like i'm five how can i make it work without having to first create the key:value pairs in the object?
Thanks in advance!
P.S. They also have to be reactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue set should do the work only your using it the wrong way:

> Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is
> also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new
> properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property
> additions (e.g. this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi').

But the function  arguments looks like this

> - {Object | Array} target
> - {string | number} propertyName/index
> - {any} value

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

In your case it should be:

```
Vue.set(state.dataObject, 'total_operation_time',  payload[1]);
Vue.set(state.dataObject, 'machine_name',  payload[2]);
```