# this.$set to update an array is not working (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

When I run this, console log gives me the updated array `xyz` but when I print it in DOM `{{xyz}}`, it does not update. Any reason why?

```
data() {
   return {
      xyz: []
   }
},
methods: {

    getDataFromXML() {

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.allxml, path => {

                fs.readFile(xmlLoc, (err, data) => {

                    if (err) throw err;

                    var XmlNode = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data.toString(), 'text/xml')
                    this.$set(this.xyz,path,XmlNode)

                })  

        })

        console.log(this.xyz)

    }
}
```

Comment: You are using set the wrong way path should be a 'in your cast' an index. See this post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181375/how-to-set-dynamic-object-values-with-vue-vuex/58181836#58181836

Comment: Did not understand, path is actually a variable. It is coming from the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using set the wrong way. You're adding a property to the array itself.

The correct for this.$set I explained here [How to set dynamic object values with Vue/Vuex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181375/how-to-set-dynamic-object-values-with-vue-vuex/58181836#58181836)

Here I create an example one button manipulate's the array with set. (The thing you are doing in your example)
The other one adds an element to the array (https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/ZEEzJpL?editors=1011)

```
    <div id="app">

   <h1>Content of array {{ data }}</h1>
   <h1>Array property alpa <span style="color: red">{{ data.alpha }}<span></h1>

    <v-btn @click="set1">manipulate array with $set</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="set2">add to array with push</v-btn>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      data: ['test']
    }
  } ,
  methods: {
    set1() {
      this.$set(this.data, 'alpha', 'xyz')

    },
    set2() {
      this.data.push('xyz')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check this as I moved to a different approach to solve this problem.

Comment: What if that xyz comes from a function. When i replace it with a dynamic value, it does not come on the DOM.

Comment: What is your xyz returning?

Comment: an url to a list of images

Comment: as you want to combine to arrays you'll have to use concat https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array. Keep in mind concat always return a new array. `this.data = this.data.concat(xyz)`